# acts_as_api rails query for non related field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've two tables which are related say A and B. A has has_many to B and B belongs_to A. However I've a field in A stored say A.account_number. And A is totally unrelated to table C which is accounts table. D has account details like addresses and other details. C has has_many relation to D and D belongs_to C. Now using acts_as_api in A and B . I wrote a big query which almost fetches every field I need except for the account and acoount details. How do I get this details using acts_as_api. I tried using calling scopes sub resource method. but it did not work. Any ideas. Please share. I'm new to rails. Here is my code.
Let's Say

```
   A-> item_people
   B-> item_people_roles
   C-> people_accounts
   D-> people_account_details
```

Class ItemPeople

```
class  ItemPeople < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many:item_people_roles, class_name => "ItemPeopleRole", :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_people_roles, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank

acts_as_api

  api_accessible :bill_rewriting do |bill|
   bill.add :account_number
   bill.add :item_people_roles
  end
end
```

Class ItemPeopleRoles

```
class  ItemPeopleRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :messages
  belongs_to :item_people, :class_name => "ItemPeople"


  acts_as_api

  api_accessible :bill_rewriting do |bill|
    bill.add :item_people_id, :as => :shipper_id, :if => lambda{|u|u.role_type_code=="SHIPPER"}
    bill.add :item_people_id, :as => :consignee_id, :if => lambda{|u|u.role_type_code=="CONSIGNEE"}
    bill.add :item_people_id, :as => :ship_to_id, :if => lambda{|u|u.role_type_code=="SHIPTO"}
   end

end
```

Class C People

```
class  People < ActiveRecord::Base
#  This model has account number
# account type fields
end
```

Class D People_Details

```
class  PeopleDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
#  This model has address1, address2, name1, name2 

end
```

Now according to people's role there in the itempeopleroles, I need to get people and people details fields in acts_as_api of ItemPeople. Hope I'm clear now

Comment: Hello Sai, Please try to format better your question ;) Right now it is really hard to figure out what is going on... Please deliver us code like other users do in their questions.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for looking into my question. I added code there. I need to get shipper,consignee details from people's table and Peoples Details tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is via a template Proc/lambda

```
api_accessible :public do |template|
  template.add lambda { |record,options|
     # look at options, and use those to build your custom data
     return [the correct data]
  }, :as => :a_magic_field
end
```

Then in your controller, get a results set, "annotate" it, and then render it.

```
raw_results = Model.where(... some where conditions ....)
results = raw_results.as_api_response(:public, ... [some other options to appear in your lambda])
```

And finally render it:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render :json => results, :callback => params[:callback]}
  format.xml {render :xml => results}
end
```

With this, you can write any code you want inside your lambda to navigate your data structures, regardless of how it is laid out.   How it will perform is another question....

Answer (score 0):

(I can't add comments yet).

If A has A.account_number and C is the table of accounts, why don't you have associations between A and C (and maybe even A and D as well as C and D)?

My "answer" is to add those associations and then just use the proper :include syntax.  I don't really see what acts_as_api is providing.

Comment: Categorically they are not related. This is a much larger project, where I cant make association for two different category tables. Already the design in place. I need to do something with these tables...!